# LASt 6 records of the output of the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

The following is the stored procedure and "I want to fetch the LATEST SIX 
INVOICES FOR EACH CUSTOMER"

THERE COULD BE MORE INVOICES FOR EACH CUSTOMER BUT I HAVE TO FETCH ONLY 
WHICH ARE LATEST 6 INVOICES.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SCA_M_CUSTSOINV_REFRESH]
  @COMP_CD NVARCHAR(20)='',
  @USER_CD NVARCHAR(20)='',
  @USER_TYPE NVARCHAR(1)=''
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SLSHIST_DATE NVARCHAR(10)

SELECT 
   @SLSHIST_DATE = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH,-SLSHIST_MTH,dbo.[GetCountryDate]()),120)
FROM SET_MASTER

WITH SUBQUERY AS 
(SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.CUST_CD ORDER BY C.INV_KEY DESC) "ROW_ID",
   A.CUST_CD,C.SO_KEY "TXN_KEY",
   C.INV_NO, C.INV_KEY, C.INV_DT, C.INV_STATUS, C.NET_TTL_TAX AS INV_AMT
 FROM 
    (SELECT DIST_CD, SLSMAN_CD, CUST_CD FROM T_CA_SLSMANCUST 
     WHERE DIST_CD = @COMP_CD AND SLSMAN_CD = @USER_CD) A
INNER JOIN TXN_INVOICE C ON C.CUST_CD=A.CUST_CD
                         AND C.INV_DT >= @SLSHIST_DATE
)
SELECT 
    CUST_CD, TXN_KEY, INV_NO, INV_KEY, INV_DT, INV_STATUS, INV_AMT,
    CASE ROW_ID WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END "LAST_INV"
FROM SUBQUERY
ORDER BY CUST_CD,INV_KEY
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: How do you know which ones are the "latest"?? What is the ordering critiera?? INV_KEY? Some date (which one)??

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `ROW_ID` by `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.CUST_CD ORDER BY C.INV_KEY DESC)` and the last invoice is the one with ROW_ID = 1 so don't you just need to add `WHERE ROW_ID <= 6` as below?

```
   SELECT 
        CUST_CD, TXN_KEY, INV_NO, INV_KEY, INV_DT, INV_STATUS, INV_AMT,
        CASE ROW_ID WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END "LAST_INV"
    FROM SUBQUERY
    WHERE ROW_ID <= 6
    ORDER BY CUST_CD,INV_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 6 * FROM invoices ORDER BY date DESC
```